# Azure CDN responding with strange result

Tags: azure-cdn

Our azure CDN suddenly started responding with the following result:

We tried restarting the CDN with no result. Source file is publi availible through the blob store.

[image: strange]

Thanks for any help

Larsi

Comment: Vary strange, i hade the same issue, but later that day it started to work again. Interested to hear an explanation to this phenonmena.

Comment: Is this issue still persist ?

Comment: No, the error was only present for a day or two (during the weekend). Feel free to give an answer I can accept.